# Change the height of the appWidget programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

Could we change programmatically and dynamically the **height** of the **appWidget** at runtime depending to the displayed components of the **listview**.

Comment: No, you can't. Height is set either from metadata(<appwidget-provider/>) or if you allow to resize by user

Comment: Thank you Selvin for answering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The size of the app widget is managed by the user, with the assistance of the home screen, not you. You suggest sizing using the app widget metadata, but the actual sizing is out of your hands.

After all:

- Not all home screens allow app widgets to change size by any means, due to limitations in the home screen implementation
- Your app widget may be adjacent to other things (e.g., other app widgets, shortcuts), where your app widget changing size would affect those other things
- Just because *you* want the app widget to be bigger does not mean that the *user* wants the app widget to be bigger

Comment: Thank you sir for the explanation